# Random generator for exam class in Physics or Chemistry

Tags: exam, chemistry, random-numbers, latex-misc, physics

I would like to create a exam class such as:

1. I could include random generator of both numbers and units for conversion factors in physics and chemistry. In particular, what I wish is a pseudorandom generator code that allowed me to generate this output:

   ```
   $ 3.34\cdot 10^{-5}\dfrac{m}{s}$ to $\dfrac{km}{h}$
   ```

   (the random variables should be the figures, the power of ten AND the units in the fractions.
2. I could include a random generator of chemical compounds (of course, as it happens with units, I can not in principle create a random generator of chemical compounds). What I want is to create a list of chemical compounds arranged by formula and/or name. E.g.:

   ```
   a) $Fe_{2}O_{3}$
   b) Chromium(III) oxide
   ...
   ```

   Any idea or suggestion of how could I create them? Any package/s I should create or check?

Post edit: should I created a whole randomgenerator list with pgf and the tikz package for every case?

Thanks.

Post edit(II): is not latex working on the equations in this stack section?

Answer (score 0):

A humble start.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% See "94.3.6 Pseudo-random functions" and 
  % "95.3 Pseudo-Random Numbers" of https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

\pgfmathsetseed{6}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[Between 0 and 1, uniform] \pgfmathparse{rnd}\pgfmathresult
    \item[Between $-1$ and 1, uniform] \pgfmathparse{rand}\pgfmathresult
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
*(https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)*

Comment: So, the issue is to create a macro with the item list, is that right? But I don't get how could i get e.g., {number+S.I.unit} for the mathematical stuff from the pseudorandom generator, and {chemical compound} using my favourite chem packages. A small example could be useful for me...Should I be more explicit? I will rewrite my question for details...

Comment: @riemannium Sorry, I am busy at the moment (working on a public talk).

Answer (score 0):

This is a plain pdfTeX solution using the `\pdfuniformdeviate` primitive from pdfTeX to generate uniformly distributed random integers.

```latex
%% Useful TeX macros

\def\nul{\noexpand\nul}
\def\gobble#1{}

\def\repeated#1#2{%
    \ifnum#1>0 %
        #2%
        \expandafter\repeated\expandafter{\the\numexpr #1-1\relax}{#2}%
    \fi%
}

% Not necessary
\def\map#1#2{%
    \mapA{#1}#2\nul%
}
\def\mapA#1#2{%
    \ifx\nul#2%
        \let\next=\gobble%
    \else%
        #1{#2}%
        \let\next=\mapA%
    \fi%
    \next{#1}%
}

\def\commap#1#2{%
    \commapA{#1}#2,\nul,%
}
\def\commapA#1#2,{%
    \ifx\nul#2%
        \let\next=\gobble%
    \else%
        #1{#2}%
        \let\next=\commapA%
    \fi%
    \next{#1}%
}

%% Macros for randomness

\let\mappingmethod=\commap
\newcount\countA

% \createmap{<name>}{<mapable elements>} -> creates an indexable map of the <mapable elements>
\def\createmap#1#2{%
    \countA=0\relax%
    \def\createmapA##1{%
        \advance\countA by 1\relax%
        \expandafter\def\csname m@#1@\the\countA\endcsname{##1}%
    }%
    \mappingmethod\createmapA{#2}%
    \expandafter\edef\csname m@#1@len\endcsname{\the\countA}%
}

% Gets length of map
\def\maplen#1{%
    \csname m@#1@len\endcsname%
}
% Gets element from map at index
\def\indexmap#1#2{%
    \csname m@#1@#2\endcsname%
}
% Gets random element from map
\def\randindexmap#1{%
    \indexmap{#1}{\the\numexpr\pdfuniformdeviate\maplen{#1}+1\relax}
}

% Generates random number in [#1, #2]
\def\irand#1#2{%
    \the\numexpr\pdfuniformdeviate\numexpr #2-#1+1\relax+#1\relax%
}

\def\declen{3}
% Generates real random number whose integer part is in [#1, #2], and the decimal length is <= \declen
\def\rrand#1#2{%
    \irand{#1}{#2}%
    {\edef\declenA{\irand0\declen}
    \ifnum\declenA>0 %
        .%
        \repeated{\numexpr\declenA-1\relax}{\irand09}%
        \irand19%
    \fi}%
}

%% Creating macros which will actually be used

\createmap{spaceunits}{mm,cm,m,km}
\createmap{timeunits}{ms,s,m,h}
% \randsu -> generate random space unit
\def\randsu{{\rm\randindexmap{spaceunits}}}
% \randtu -> generate random time unit
\def\randtu{{\rm\randindexmap{timeunits}}}

%% Example
$\rrand1{10}\cdot\rrand0{10}\frac\randsu\randtu$
```

A rundown of what's happening here:

- `\createmap` takes two parameters: a name and comma separated values and creates from this a "hasmap" of sorts of the specified names and values (the keys are the indexes of the values).

  Instead of comma separated values, if you set `\mappingmethod` to `\map` you can group the values instead (eg. `\createmap{example}{{first}{second}{third}}`), this is useful if the values contain commas themselves).
- `\maplen` gives you the size of the map (the number of values), `\indexmap` indexes a map by the given index (the second parameter), `\randomindexmap` indexes a map randomly.
- `\irand` gives a random integer in the specified range (inclusive). While `\rrand` gives a random real number where the integer part is in the specified range (inclusive) and the number of numbers after the decimal point is given by `\declen`.

So we then create two maps, `spaceunits` and `timeunits` which have different spatial and temporal units, and macros `\randsu` and `\randtu` which index these maps randomly for convenience (`\randsu` gives a random spatial unit and `\randtu` gives a random temporal unit).

You can probably use `\createmap` and `\randomindexmap` for your second question.

Comment: After adding `\bye`, this still don't compile. `Undefined control sequence.
l.96 $\rrand1{10}\cdot\rrand0{10}\frac`. What is `\frac`? This isn't a TeX command. After replacing it by "\over", I obtain "6.7∙4.67" at numerator and "kmh" at denominator. Am I missing something?

Comment: @quark67 I assumed that whoever was using this was using LaTeX, but you can define it yourself with `\def\frac#1#2{{{#1}\over{#2}}}` (you need to properly group the numerator and denominator)

Comment: Ok, I though you provides TeX code because you speak about pdfTeX, not pdfLaTeX in your answser. And because there is no `\documentclass{...}... \end{document}`. Sorry for the mistake. It's probably better to add `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}, `\end{document}` to avoid any confusion.

Comment: You're totally right. I should be more consistent, thank you for your input!